# Async communication microservices : How to notify end user after operation completed successfully

Tags: asynchronous, microservices, messaging, communication, system-design

I am using async communication with messaging Queues in one of my personal project.

I am stuck at how can I notify my end user (who is my client basically - who is making request) once  the operation has been completed .

I understand in some of the long job, we can notify trough email once its finish .

But what if in the case of normal operations like , let say my user is updating his profile , call goes to my backend service - backend service will push one message to update profile to messaging system and on the spot I will respond back to my client with some response. (actual update has not completed yet as it will be done via messaging queue - async way) .

Now here is the question how can I notify my end user that his profile is updated once the operation is completed via messaging queue .

I want to notify my user in the application itself , not via email or any other way . It should be real time notification just like response or something so by using that my client developer can show appropriate message.

updating is only example here , it can be anything .

Comment: If you just want to let the client know that you are working on their request, but haven't finished yet, you should return status code 202 (accepted)

Comment: write a scheduler that polls after a period and sends a notification for the completed task. If your db provides some event after pushing data, you can use that also.